# Retrieving .swf from website

Tags: animation, flash

I was wondering if you guys can help me out. Im making a website for an authorized Dish dealer. Ive been trying to retrieve the flash animation on dish.com. I was able to get it through firefox with 'Page Info' but all I get is a black rectangle without no animation. Its a .swf, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible issues there.

There's a chance that the movie is loading something from that domain, which will not get loaded when the container movie is loaded in another domain due to cross-domain policy issues (and security sandbox restrictions).

Also, in its code the developer might have made it to check the URL and restricted some actions accordingly.

Another possibility is, it might be using some data that it gathers from the page source, or a server-side script which you might not be providing it.

These are the most likely possibilities I can think of, but if I get a chance to think more I'm sure I can come up with many others.